# При свойстве float элемент не делает отступы сверху

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

```
<div class="block">
                    <img src="style/images/photo.png">
                    <h1>Contrary to popular</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots 
                    in a piece </p>
            </div>
```

[image: Требуемый вид]

Я попытался решить данную задачу путем следующим образом:

```
.block      {
     height: 200px;
     margin: 0;
}
.block img  {
     float:left;
     margin:40px 0px 0px 44px;
}
.block h1 { 
     display:inline;
     margin:50px 0px 0px 25px;
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Но заголовок вовсе не делает отступы от верха блока. Почему это происходит и как это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените `display: inline;`(`margin-top` и `margin-bottom` игнорируются) на `display: inline-block;`

```css
.block {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}

.block img {
  float: left;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 44px;
}

.block h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  <h1>Contrary to popular</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @korjunb вы можете поблагодарить автора ответа зелёной галочкой слева от текста ответа